# ansible hash to json to jinja template

Tags: json, dictionary, templates, hash, ansible

i got the following and stuck by getting the right answer. i got a dict that i want to template with item.key in file name and all the values in the template.

```
my_dict:
  name1:
    { path=/x/y/z, action=all, filter=no },
    { path=/a/b/c, action=some, filter=yes }
  name2:
    { path=/z/y/x, action=nothing, filter=no },
    { path=/c/b/a, action=all, filter=yes }

 tasks:
   - name: generate check config
     template:
       src: check.j2
       dest: "{{ config_dir }}/{{ item.key }}-directories.json"
       owner: Own
       group: Wheel
       mode: 0644
     with_dict:
       - "{{ my_dict }}"
     when:
       - my_dict is defined
     become: true
```

My template looks like

```
{
"configs": [

{% for value in my_dict %}
{
"path": "{{ value.path }}",
"action": "{{ value.action }}",
{% if value.filter is defined %}
"filter": "{{ value.filter }}"
{% endif %}
}{% if !loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
]
}
```

So i tested so much that now i dont see any forest cause of too many trees.

Above should result in 2 files.
File name = name1-directories.json
Content:

```
{
"configs": [
{
"path": /x/y/z,
"action": all,
"filter": no
},
{
"path": /a/b/c,
"action": some,
"filter": yes
}
]
}
```

Thx in Advance

Comment: Can you simplify your question and add the result you want to achieve.

Comment: @gentux Is your question answered? Do you have more questions?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with the following. I see some problems with your current solution.

1. You're template references the value of the array items with `value.<key>` when it should instead read `item.value.<key>`.
2. `with_dict` expects a dict, but you're passing an array containing a dict as the only element. In yaml, `-` denotes array elemtents. To use that correctly you just write: `with_dict: "{{ my_dict }}"`
3. Using the shorthand yaml syntax is discouraged in ansible as it makes the playbooks harder to read.

I would suggest you do the following:

There is a jinja2 Filter that just converts your dict to json:

```
{{ dict_variable | to_json }} # or
{{ dict_variable | to_nice_json }}
```

The second one makes it human readable. What you're currently trying to do may work ( haven't looked into it so thoroughly) but it's not pretty and error prone.

To make it work with the jinja2 filter restructure your variables at the top the following way:

```
    my_dict:
      - name1:
          configs:
            - path: /x/y/z
              action: all
              filter: no
            - path: /a/b/c
              action: some
              filter: yes
      - name2:
          configs:...
```

When the vars are formatted like this, you can just use the `copy` module to print the configs to the files like this:

```
    - name: Print the configs to the files
      copy:
        content: "{{ item.value | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: "{{ config_dir }}/{{ item.key }}-directories.json"
      with_dict: "{{ my_dict }}"
```